# Launcher for programs which need multiple commands to run

Tags: unity, command-line, bash, launcher, shortcuts

I already installed a program called CadFeko, and I can run it from terminal. To run the program, first I have to run this command

```
     . /opt/feko/6.3/bin/initfeko
```

Then I can call the program by

```
     cadfeko
```

This doesn't release the terminal. Also, if I close the program and terminal I have to run the `initfeko` again.

I tried to create a shortcut launcher for this program. I cannot figure it out, how can I use combination of these two commands on the same line. I already tried something like this in my `.desktop` file:

```
   Exec=  . /opt/feko/6.3/bin/initfeko && cadfeko
```

but this is not working for me. Please let me know if there is a solution for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this Exec line for your `.desktop` file:

```
Exec= bash -c ". /opt/feko/6.3/bin/initfeko && cadfeko"
```

`bash` will open a shell and correctly interpret the `&&`.

Comment: TX for the comment. This wasn't working last week. I tried again now and works fine. TX again :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this command:

```
. /opt/feko/6.3/bin/initfeko && cadfeko &
```

adding '&' at the end will let it run in the background the terminal auto hides

I hope that works

Comment: Thanks, This works fine in terminal, but I had no luck with launcher so far :(